# Unlisting a python list and removing element

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'm trying to remove "title" element out of this list that I scrape from the web:

```
x = 
[[(u'title', u'Goals for')], [(u'title', u'Goals against')], [(u'title', u'Penalty goal')], [(u'title', u'Goals for average')], [(u'title', u'Matches Played')], [(u'title', u'Shots on goal')], [(u'title', u'Shots Wide')], [(u'title', u'Free Kicks Received')], [(u'title', u'Offsides')], [(u'title', u'Corner kicks')], [(u'title', u'Wins')], [(u'title', u'Draws')], [(u'title', u'Losses')]]
```

I would like my final to be

```
result = ['Goals for', 'Goals against','Penalty goal','Goals for average',....]
```

But I can do `y = x[1][0][1]` => 'Goals for'
I couldn't not do `x[i][0][1]` since it is index in my for loop statement I got error

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a list comprehension:

```
>>> new = [sublist[0][1] for sublist in x]
>>> pprint.pprint(new)
[u'Goals for',
 u'Goals against',
 u'Penalty goal',
 u'Goals for average',
 u'Matches Played',
 u'Shots on goal',
 u'Shots Wide',
 u'Free Kicks Received',
 u'Offsides',
 u'Corner kicks',
 u'Wins',
 u'Draws',
 u'Losses']
```

Not sure what the `pandas` connection is, though.  If you're trying to extract a column from a `MultiIndex`, there are simpler ways.

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension (generally more common because it is clear, concise and considered Pythonic):

```
x = [[(u'title', u'Goals for')], [(u'title', u'Goals against')], [(u'title', u'Penalty goal')], [(u'title', u'Goals for average')], [(u'title', u'Matches Played')], [(u'title', u'Shots on goal')], [(u'title', u'Shots Wide')], [(u'title', u'Free Kicks Received')], [(u'title', u'Offsides')], [(u'title', u'Corner kicks')], [(u'title', u'Wins')], [(u'title', u'Draws')], [(u'title', u'Losses')]]
x = [i[0][1:] for i in x]
```

Or you can use a `for` loop over the length of `x`:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i] = x[i][0][1:]
```

As was pointed out after the original answer, my other original suggestion to use Python's `del` statement (e.g. `del x[0][0][0]`) also wouldn't have worked because `tuple` does not support item deletion.

Comment: Your listcomp will produce a bunch of empty lists. :^)

Comment: Good catch, DSM!  I didn't notice the 3rd level of nesting. ;)

Answer (score 1):

just have a try:

```
x = [[('title', 'Goals for')], [('title', 'Goals against')], [('title', 'Penalty goal')], [('title', 'Goals for average')], [('title', 'Matches Played')], [('title', 'Shots on goal')], [('title', 'Shots Wide')], [('title', 'Free Kicks Received')], [('title', 'Offsides')], [('title', 'Corner kicks')], [('title', 'Wins')], [('title', 'Draws')], [('title', 'Losses')]]
print([element[0][1] for element in x ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Other solution:

```
>>> map(lambda a: a[0][1], x)
... [u'Goals for', u'Goals against', u'Penalty goal', u'Goals for average', u'Matches Played', u'Shots on goal', u'Shots Wide', u'Free Kicks Received', u'Offsides', u'Corner kicks', u'Wins', u'Draws', u'Losses']
>>>
```